# Set field for object using field name (Java Reflection)

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

I have an array with field names  - `fieldNamesArr` and array with values for those fields - `fieldValuesArr`. Also I have `Object obj`,created form `class Class` using `.newInstanse();`.

How can I set appropriate fields in `obj` using this two arrays?
(we're assuming that `obj` has all of this fields and they are public)

```
Class ourClass = Definer.getClassByName(tmpStrArr[1]);
obj = ourClass.newInstance();

List<String> fieldNamesArr = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> fieldValuesArr = new ArrayList<>();
```

[remark 1] Supposed that  `obj` doesn't have a complex fields (just primitive types)

Comment: If I simply paste the question title into Google I get lots of results. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a solution. It should look something like that, I guess:

```
int i=0;        
for (String tmpStr: fieldNamesArr) {
   Field field = ourClass.getField(tmpStr);   

   //converting string from fieldValuesArr[i] to required type //   

   field.set(obj,value);
   i++
}
```